# How to use max with swift3?

Tags: swift, swift3, max, cgfloat

i am getting an error for the bellow code:

```
var bubbleWidth:CGFloat!
bubbleWidth:CGFloat = max( CGFloat(15) , bubbleWidth )
```

here is the error message:
**no candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'cgfloat!'**

this code was working without any problem on swift 2 , i don't know why i am getting that error now !

EDIT:
here is my real code:

```
    var bubbleWidth:CGFloat!
        bubbleWidth = imageView.frame.width + 11

    bubbleWidth =   max( CGFloat(15) ,
                          bubbleWidth )
```

and here is the error that i am receving:
[image]

Edit:
please note: i don't want to assign value to bubbleWidth, like that
var bubbleWidth:CGFloat = -1

Thanks

Comment: `bubbleWidth` in the `max` expression is `nil` (no value). What do you expect?

Comment: is the `:CGFloat` in the second line even valid syntax?

Comment: do you see the typo? it should be `CGFloat` not `CGFLoat`

Comment: Even without the CGFLoat typo does that code not compile in any Swift version.

Comment: @vadian no it's not nil, in my code i assign value before the max function. also this is a compile error not run time error

Comment: @MartinR this code run in swift 2. without any problem. please note that in my code i assign value to the bubble width before the max function

Comment: @david: I copied your code into Xcode 7: It does **not** compile with Swift 2.

Comment: @dirtydanee thank you for your comment.  yes i see , in my code it's CGFLoat . this is not the code problem.

Comment: @luk2302 thank you for your comment. in my code it's CGFLoat . this is not the code problem.

Comment: @david: *"in my code it's CGFLoat"* – There is no `CGFLoat` type. Please copy/paste your real code.

Comment: @MartinR ,thank you for your comment ,  i've added my real code with picture witch shows the my error. i am wondering why max can't accept CGFloat!

Comment: @david You *have to* pay attention to capitalization. It's not an option. While CGFloat is a type, CGFLoat is not, for example. Please. It's important also here. Because a typo *could* be the source of your issue. So, always be careful to use your real code, properly spelled.

Comment: @EricAya ,I know, please this is not the problem , i am asking how the max function can't accept CGFloat! , but can accept CGFloat . this code was working on swift 2

Comment: This is another consequence of https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md, and you have to unwrap the IUO, `bubbleWidth!` or `bubbleWidth ?? 0`.

Comment: @MartinR what's the IUO  ? what do you mean to unwarp like that: bubbleWidth =   max( CGFloat(15) ,
                          bubbleWidth! )

Comment: IUO is "implicitly unwrapped optional". Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @MartinR thank you , yes i see now that there is no error. but why ? why in swift2 there is was no need to unwarp the CGFloat! ?

Comment: Because things changed in Swift 3! The SE-0054 proposal that I linked to was implemented in Swift 3.

Comment: @MartinR could you please give me another links which describe what changed ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of [SE-0054 Abolish ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md) which has been implemented in **Swift 3:**

> However, the appearance of ! at the end of a property or variable declaration's type no longer indicates that the declaration has IUO type; rather, it indicates that (1) the declaration has optional type, and (2) the declaration has an attribute indicating that its value may be implicitly forced. ...
>
> If the expression can be explicitly type checked with a strong optional type, it will be. However, the type checker will fall back to forcing the optional if necessary.

Now one could argue that the compiler should fall back to unwrapping
the optional in

```
bubbleWidth = max(CGFloat(15), bubbleWidth)
```

but for some reason that works only with a float *literal*

```
bubbleWidth = max(15, bubbleWidth)
```

and I am not sure if this is a bug or not. Alternatively, unwrap the value explicitly

```
bubbleWidth = max(CGFloat(15), bubbleWidth!)
```

or – better – provide a default value with the nil-coalescing operator `??`:

```
bubbleWidth = max(CGFloat(15), bubbleWidth ?? 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i really got confused , this the first time i know that i should unwrap CGfloat! . i know that i should unwrap it just if i declare it in this way CGFloat?

Comment: @david: Have a look at the SE-0054. CGFloat! is mostly treated like CGFloat? now.

Comment: could you please give an official apple link ?

Comment: I already gave you the link to SE-0054. You'll also find it on https://swift.org/blog/swift-3-0-released/.